# Redirecting from https to http with the exception of some URI's

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, uri

So the problem I am currently having is that our entire website is indexed using https. we want to redirect to http using .htaccess. the problem is that we need a couple of URIs to still use https and I am not sure how to write the exception for URIs

I know the below example would work if our site functioned like this www.example.com/account.php but our site urls are like www.example.com/index.php?l=account

```
# Turn SSL on for account
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/account\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

how can i fix this, any guidance would be appreciated.

thanks

EDIT!

So this code below I have working but I would like to make one more exception that I cant seem to get to work, I also want the root (index.php) to only use http.

I tried using...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
```

but this did not work

```
# invoke rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^l=product_detail
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^l=product_list
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^l=page_view
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/development/$1 [R=301,L]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account.php 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^l=account
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/account.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=account
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```