# redirection http to https with exceptions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have a website (lets say website.com) and using .htaccess with the following content:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I need to redirect http to https. For this, I added this line in my virtual host settings:

```
Redirect permanent / https://website.com/
```

As a result, it redirects all traffic to https

My question is I need to add exceptions to my redirection
For ex. all traffic after this route http://website.com/folder/test/* should be routed to HTTP

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow has a similar question . [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426893/htaccess-redirect-to-https-except-a-few-urls)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting from https to http with the exception of some URI's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065065/redirecting-from-https-to-http-with-the-exception-of-some-uris)

Answer (score 0):

**RewriteCond** helps in such situations

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```